# php mysql query with both "=" and "LIKE"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like below;

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Sl |   Column1   |   Column2   |   Column3   |   Column4   |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1  |   Data1A    |   Data2A    |   Data3A    |   xxxxxx    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2  |   Data1B    |   Data2B    |   Data3B    |   yyyyyy    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 3  |   Data1C    |   Data2C    |   Data3C    |   xxxxxx    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 4  |   Data1D    |   Data2D    |   Data3D    |   yyyyyy    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 5  |   Data1E    |   Data2E    |   Data3E    |   xxxxxx    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I just want to make a query with LIKE statement for columns 1,2 and 3, so that it will search for similar data in those columns with keywords. Also I want to filter the results using the data in column4, which means, I want the privilage to filter away results which will be specific to col4, either xxxxxx or yyyyyy.

I made a syntax `$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1 LIKE'%$keyword%' OR Column2 LIKE'%$keyword%' OR Column3 LIKE'%$keyword%' AND Column4 = 'xxxxxx'";`

But this is not working, and my syntax `$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1 LIKE'%$keyword%' AND Column4 = 'xxxxxx'";` is working well.

But I want to check for similarities in col2 and col3 also. But it will give me result without filtering col4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to put brackets around your `OR` conditions like so...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
 (Column1 LIKE'%$keyword%' OR Column2 LIKE'%$keyword%' OR Column3 LIKE'%$keyword%') AND Column4 = 'xxxxxx';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember how the comparative function. You need to evaluate all the OR conditions as a group and then match it with the last AND condition. You need to use brackets around the OR conditions to make them evaluate as a group.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution lies in grouping the disjunction (ORs) together, like so:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Column1 LIKE '%$keyword%' OR Column2 LIKE'%$keyword%' OR Column3 LIKE'%$keyword%') AND Column4 = 'xxxxxx'";
```